# How to detect "in call mode" android java

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, phone-call

I'm trying to detect mode when we in call. I'm using most popular example with broadcast and telephonyManager.
But there are only 3 states.

```
String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){

}
if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){

}
if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){

}
```

after some tests i found that :

1) when incoming call - than i see state = RINGING
   - accept call from this state  = OFFHOOK

2) but when im do outgoing call - state = OFFHOOK , and when another "me" on other side accept call - state still = OFFHOOK.

How to correctly detect IN_CALL_MODE (mean im speaking at current time ). ?
Can any help ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using AudioManager??

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.getMode()==AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL){
    return true;    // Active call
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: actually its not work. dont know how i test its last time.

Comment: is this need phone state permissions?